Apply segmentation of an image inside a binary mask
I have an image and a binary mask. I'd like to apply the mask to that image and then segment the skin lesion through the Chan-Vese algorithm.
I tried to BITWISE_AND the image and the mask (or the inverse of the mask) and then apply the Chan-Vese but it recognized the mask instead of the lesion.
I'll leave the image and the mask down here:

In addition, I apply Chan-Vase on the L channel of my image converted in CIE Lab.
Any help would be appreciated :)
